# Excel UDF detecting page breaks?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

I'm trying to write a UDF that returns whether the cell is at a page break.

So far I have this:

```
Function pbreak() As Boolean
   ' Application.Volatile
    pbreak = False
    Dim ra As Range
    Set ra = Application.Caller
    With ra
        For i = 1 To .Worksheet.HPageBreaks.Count
            If .Worksheet.HPageBreaks(i).Location.Row = .Row Then
                pbreak = True

            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

This returns a `#VALUE` error. I've tried debugging it, `HPageBreaks.Count` returns 3 (and there are 3 page breaks), but `HPageBreaks(i)` yields an "index out of range"-error for all pagebreaks that are below the current cell .

Is this a bug (ie .Count is wrong), or is there some special behavior with page breaks that I am missing?

Is there a way to fix this (preferably without resorting to `on error resume next`)?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: your code works OK for me (Excel 2003)

Comment: Have you tried it with a longer document? I just tested it, and it works with 3 pages or less, more tha that and it only works on the last page. Weird.

Comment: yup tried it with 7 pagebreaks. all OK. I am using Excel 2003 SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Function pbreak() As Boolean
   ' Application.Volatile
    Dim i As Integer   'the missing line
    pbreak = False
    Dim ra As Range
    Set ra = Application.Caller
    With ra
        For i = 1 To .Worksheet.HPageBreaks.Count
            If .Worksheet.HPageBreaks(i).Location.Row <= .Row Then
                If .Worksheet.HPageBreaks(i).Location.Row = .Row Then
                    pbreak = True
                    'exit the function once a page break is found.
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Else
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

EDIT: Always use `Option Explicit` & compile the code before using it.
Use of `Exit Function` inside the loop is to prevent the code from running it further, once the result is known.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks! I'm still puzzled why the hpagebreaks further down are inaccessible, especially why (or how) .count is different from the actual list length.